# How to create action sheet Delete in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I want to create action sheet same bellow picture with Delete button red color and Cancel button. How can i do that? Thanks much

[image: I want to create action sheet same bellow picture with Delete button red color and Cancel button. How can i do that? Thanks much]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use that code make make delete button as  destructiveButton

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to delete this backup?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Backup" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to delete this backup ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete backup" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  UIActionSheet *objActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"XYZ Message"
                         delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Backup"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ready codes are available on github for this type of action sheet.

1. [RDActionSheet for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rdactionsheet)
2. [action-sheet-blocks for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/action-sheet-blocks)
3. [LBActionSheet for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lbactionsheet)
4. [SHActionSheetBlocks for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/shactionsheetblocks)

Comment: Or even `UIActionSheet`. There is nothing in that screenshot that he can't do with a `UIActionSheet` and a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample project from https://github.com/russj/MBActionSheet/ and can customize your action sheet. You can design your buttons and add to actionsheet using following code

```
- (void)createButton:(CGRect)frm buttonTitile:(NSString *)title buttonIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = frm;
    if(index==0){
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if(index==1){
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTag:index];
    [sheetView addSubview:btn];
}
```

and call this method where you are creating action sheet.