# Presenting choices to user in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiview

I am writing an iPhone app. My next step is to create a card object. I know how to do this theoretically, but my problem is coming from my lack of experience in Xcode.

This is my add item page
[image: Add Item]

I want the user to specify a name and then choose an icon, either from the 3 most popular choices, another page of premade options, or take their own picture and use that.

Now, how do I show those choices in a way that the user can select one and I can collect their response? Right now, they are simply buttons, I can add my background image to them, but I don't know how to record their response. I would like it to show them their selection by adding that shadow around the box.

I'm not sure if a button is the best approach.

Also, I will need the same selection behavior for the image they take themselves, but I figure if I get the icon choices to work, I can figure out using a picture taken by the user.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Remove the buttons and use a UITableView.

Comment: I would create button "Select image" below the uiimageview. This button would present action sheet -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692573/how-to-create-action-sheet-delete-in-ios where you would have two options a) select form existng b) take a picture. Then I would probably use Grid View (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) to present the existing icons and uiimagepicker for taking pictures :)

Comment: Can UITableView be formatted to be more of a grid type look? I don't want it to look like a table per say.

Comment: @Yanchi That looks to be a solid idea. I hadn't thought about the action sheets. I was attempting to use the collection view but hadn't gotten it yet. Thanks! If you want to post that as an answer i'll give you the green checkmark lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create button "Select image" below the uiimageview.

This button would present   [action sheet](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-create-a-dynamic-action-sheet/) where you would have two options

a) select form existing

b) take a picture.

Then I would probably use [Grid view](http://appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial) to present the existing icons and  [UIImagePicker](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/) for taking pictures :)